# How do I fill canvas with background color when pattern is no-repeat

Tags: html, canvas

this is what I have done

[image]

and I need my canvas with something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### How to use the canvas!

Two images you supplied are full of possibilities but I can not guess which possibility it is that you have in your mind.

To answer the question as to how?

You start with a canvas

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```

then you get the context `CanvasRenderingContext2D` by calling `getContext`

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

I have called it ctx. It provides a good set of drawing functions and properties that will help you find the picture you have in your mind.

You can find out how to use the API at MDN. It provides a good blend of technical reference and many simple examples to help you learn how to do all that the canvas is designed to do.

A good place to start [MDN learn how to use the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

Take a little time to study the various properties and methods that you get with the 2D context. Try them out and see how you progress.

If you have problems with some parts of the 2D API please do come back to SO and ask for additional help.

Currently without extra information in regards to your question there is not much anyone can do to give you an answer.